# TFS Release successful but the intended build not getting deployed

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, release-management

I am using TFS 2015 automated release management. The release shows successful after picking up the appropriate build from the list, but if I check the live website the application number does not change and also the changes are not getting deployed. It means the dll's are not being picked up the way they should.

Comment: Can you share the build and release logs (succeed deployed and not deployed) and on the OneDrive? (Remove personal information)

Answer (score -1):

If you have picked up the appropriate build for the release, then TFS server should also pick up all related dlls.

You could try to manually do the deploy and check the live wesite, the application number to see if changes are getting deployed or not.

This will narrow down if the issue is related to build or not. If you got the same result, I'm afraid the dlls are not generated properly in that particular build.

If not, also try to manually create the release with some build and compare the logs with automate generated release.

---

Update:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. So when you say "try to manually create the release with some build and compare the logs with automate generated release"- Can you please tell me where do I find these logs. Would Really appreciate it.

Comment: @RohitJachak You could check the log option when you open a specific  Release. I'm using TFS2017 version, there maybe something different with TFS2015. You could also down the related logs as `.zip` file. Details you could see my update screenshot.